# Compare Properties/Strings in freemarker templates for keycloak

Tags: java, templates, keycloak, freemarker

I'm working on freemarker templates for keycloak.

In an if condition, I'm trying to compare two strings, but both are in variables/properties. I want to compare the error message, which is delivered through "message.summary" to a property that I have set. The idea behind this is that I don't need to change every single template when I want to change this particular error message to be checked. I tried different combinations and the nearest I got was:

```
<#if message.summary == properties.messageToCheck>
```

With this "solution" I get a numberFormatException / IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number.

Is it even possible to compare two "properties" in freemarker? If yes, how can I accomplish this?